# Div will not float right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the blue box with the number 2 in it to be inline with the user requests button wording. I have been messing around with this code for some time.

The div that I need to float right is this...

```
.admin_alert_out_panel {
    width: 10%;
    border: 1px solid #0000CC;
    background-color: #0000CC;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

I have tried `inline`, `inline-block`, I added a `float: left;` to the `panel_buttons` class. Nothing is working.

Here is a fiddle I made up to show what I am trying to do...

https://jsfiddle.net/5mf989jL/6/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just use button tags instead of input type="button" so that you can place it inside the tags and change div to span

```
<button class="panel_buttons arrowBtn" id='user_requests_button'>
    User Requests <span class="admin_alert_out_panel">2</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<input>` with `<button>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/5mf989jL/27/

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you still need css):

```
<div class="admin_alert_out_panel" style="float: right">
```

I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some stuff. Now it works fine with a div. Here's the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/5mf989jL/40/

It works best with a div.

```
<div class="special panel_buttons arrowBtn"  id='user_requests_button'>
  User Requests<div class="admin_alert_out_panel">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try this.This is working!..](https://jsfiddle.net/john411/xma7b67e/)

```
.panel-buttons{    
display:inline;
}
```

You need to change in panel-buttons and need to adjust width of panel to avoid collapse...

Comment: An explanation would make the answer better.